# Reactjs - Not able to render in my component's this.state.item values from my servlet api

Tags: reactjs

From my ReactJS application, am submitting a JSONRequest to External system via Java Servlet and getting response from that Servlet. Those response i have to set it in my React component.

But, am having issue. That am not able to set the values for the very first response. If i manually refresh the page those values are setting properly. And then, if i submitting request for 2nd time with the same form values that time am able to render the response values without any manual refresh.

During very first time response of the form am unable to set the response value.

Please find my below code that am trying.

```
class Orders extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.publishToOracle = this.publishToOracle.bind(this);
  }

  publishToOracle(id) {
    var item=this.state.item;
    ajax({
      url: 'api/publish_oracle',
      method: 'POST',
      data: { id: id }

    },
   (data) => {
     if (data.error == null) {
       alert('Order has been published to Oracle Successfully') 
       item.oracle_number=data.result.oracle_number;
       this.setState({ view: 'Details', item: data.result});
       console.log("Order Number-->"+JSON.stringify(this.state.item.oracle_number)); // Oracle Number is printing here every time. But not in the component.
     } else if (data.error != null) {
       alert(data.error);
     }
   });
  }


  render() {
    if (this.state.view == 'Details') {
      return (
        <Details
          item={ this.state.item }
          publishToOracle={this.publishToOracle}
        />
      );
    }
  }
}



class Details extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { item: props.item };
  }

  handlePublishToOracle(e) {
    var item = this.state.item;
    alert("Publishing to Oracle");
    e.preventDefault();
    item["oracle_order_number"] = "";
    item["oracle_response_message"]="";
    item["oracle_response_status"]="";
    this.props.publishToOracle(item.id);
 }

 handleActionButtons() {
   if(this.state.action == "PublishToOracle") {
     return (
       <button
         type="submit"
         onClick={ this.handlePublishToOracle}
       >
         Publish To Oracle
       </button>
     );
   }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <select
        name="action"
        value={this.state.action}
        onChange={this.handleAction}
      >
        <option value="PublishToOracle"> Publish To Oracle</option>
      </select>
      { this.handleActionButtons() }
      <input
        name="oracle_number"
        type="text"
        maxLength="20"
        value={ this.state.item.oracle_number }
      />
     );
   }
}
```

Actually, the functionality of the API is to get the response save it in my MongoDB and render in React UI.

Comment: What does it mean "That am not able to set the values for the very first response"? Did you expect to see the <Details> tag on the page?

Comment: @boaz_shuster - Please find the screenshot. `this.state.item.order_number` during very first time response form API. Value is not rendering in this component. And when am refreshing the page, its populating.

Comment: You are passing `publishToOracle` to `Details` but then you access `publishToOracleEBS`

Comment: @G4bri3l - Sorry, it was typo error and corrected now.

Comment: That's odd. Because I thought that at the first rendering, the promise isn't complete which means that item is undefined. Thus, you should have gotten "item is undefined" error message but somehow you didn't.

Comment: Yes, thats my confusion. Or., after the successful API request., how do i re-render the page. Because, am able to see the response stored in Mongo.

Comment: Where does `ajax` method come from? `render` method in `Orders` class is a side-effect function, it only returns sometimes, which is a really bad structure. `publishToOracle` is a callback function in `Details`, but without render `Details`, there's no way to access this function. `button` doesn't need `type="submit"`, since you like to manage its behavior in js and `preventDefault`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is due to the below elements are undefined for the very first time. so am creating those elements with empty value and once we get the response from the api, its settings those values in the created elements and its works fine.

```
 item["oracle_order_number"] = "";
 item["oracle_response_message"]="";
 item["oracle_response_status"]="";
 this.props.publishToOracleEBS(item);
```

This solution has been updated in my questions too.